# Can someone protect this question?

Tags: discussion, editing

Spammers attempt to edit this answer of mine on a regular basis.  Can the question be protected to prevent this?

[Connecting Roland vb-99 to Personal Computer (USB)](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4222/connecting-roland-vb-99-to-personal-computer-usb/5352#5352)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207837/192187

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spam edits such as these should be automatically rejected if the post is over 400 characters long<sup>1</sup>, so I've edited it to be longer. If you encounter this going forward, take a few minutes to flesh out answers that appear to be targets for spam - the longer your post, the easier it'll be for the system to automatically detect and reject spam.

<sup>1</sup> *According to [Shog9](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/users/93/shog9).*

Comment: It appears no spam edits have made it past the spam burninator since the edit to lengthen the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I just checked out this post and you were right that there appeared to be an edit attempted through some sort of spam-robot. I rejected the answer as 'vandalism', so this type of activity shouldn't generally be a problem; it won't get through unless a high reputation user explicitly 'approves' it (don't do that, obviously).

This isn't really a good use case for protecting a post. Besides, 'protecting' a post wont actually prevent someone from editing its contents.

Comment: For the past few weeks, there are probably 10 edit attempts per day.  Even now after NReilingh was kind enough to edit my answer to bring it up to snuff.  I'm pretty tired of the notifications about it, and I can't delete the answer.  I don't see what the big issue is about protecting it, because it would solve the problem completely.  If you won't protect it, please delete my account for this stack.

Comment: Why is it not a good use case?  It seriously attracts around 10 useless, spam edits per **day**.  Protecting the question would *completely* solve the problem.

Comment: @ana http://music.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history Is there any way we can block the IP(s)?

Comment: The attempted edits have been coming in through a wide array of different IP addresses, so IP blocking wouldn't be an effective fix. @cornbreadninja Now that the length of the post has been adjusted, I'm hopeful that this will do the trick.